# Calculating range of parameters for parametrization of hemisphere.

Tags: self-learning, spherical-coordinates

I have a hemisphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1\ ;z\geqslant 0.$ I want to represent it by the vector representation $$\vec r(u,v)=\sin u \cos v\ \hat i+\sin u\sin v \ \hat j+\cos u \ \hat k$$

I am having a very silly problem of figuring out the ranges of $u\ \&\ v$.

For $u$ , I can guess that since $\cos u\geqslant 0\ ;\ u\in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ . but I am not getting how to calculate the range of $v$ . Could someone help?

Comment: @HKLee Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 0):

Correction: Take $u\in[0, \pi/2]$ then  $v$ is simply $0$ to $2\pi$

Comment: I initially took that , but it resulted in a wrong answer!

Comment: This is the usual parametrization from $(x,y,z)$ to $(r,v,u)$ why do you think it is wrong? (here $r=1$).

Comment: Could you do one thing for me? Just do this simple integration and tell me the answer. $$\int_v\int_u|\sin ^3u|\ du\ dv$$ to be integated over the ranges of $u$ and $v$.

Comment: since $\sin^3u$ is antisymmetric around $u=0$ you have to separate it to 2 integrals over $[0,\pi/2]$ and over $[-\pi/2,0]$ the first gives you $2/3$ the second $-2/3$ since you have $|\sin^3u|$ in the integrand the second is taken as $2/3$ so the total is $4/3$. The integral is:  $\frac{1}{12} \cos 3 u -\frac{3}{4} \cos u $

Comment: So the net answer should be $$\int_0^{2\pi} {4\over 3}dv$$ Right?

Comment: Yes you have to multiply by $2\pi$

Comment: But the **right** answer is given to be $${4\pi\over 3}$$

Comment: The indefinite integral of $\sin^3u$ is actually $-\cos u+\cos^3/3$. It comes out to be 2/3 on the $[0,\pi/2]$ interval and 4/3 is the result for the absolute value on the full interval. . I don't see why they have it differently.

Comment: This is originally a apart of the question of the book Apostol Calculus volume II. Question $12.10.1(a)$ . Check for yourself the answer,(given at the back of the book) if you want to.

Comment: I may have misunderstood you initially. If the original problem was requested just to calculate $|sin^3 u|$ over half the sphere, then the integral should be only in the range $[0,\pi/2]$ then you get 2/3 for the integral. (then there is really no reason for the absolute value). If we do the integral over the full range $[-\pi/2,\pi,2]$ then it is over the complete sphere.

Comment: Isn't $[-\pi, \pi]$ the full range?

Comment: No. for $u$ we need just half a period $[0,\pi/2]$. Because if $v$ runs over $2\pi$ that's enough for the radius vector (here $=1$) to run over all points on the sphere.

Comment: Done. Thanks...